# Pairing multiple javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to solve a problem I have with multiple javascript arrays.

So basically the result I want is to match the arrays of a dropdown box with other values from other arrays that I will display.

The arrays contain different values, but the order is the most important thing

---

```
var array1 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22];
var array2 = [30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50];
var array3 = [36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54, 56];
```

Let's say the user selects number 4, then I need to somehow select 32 in array2 and 38 in array3.

Any suggestions are gladly accepted, Thanks!

Comment: Just use `array2[array1.indexOf(4))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Get the index from the first array, with [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

   ```
   var index = array1.indexOf(4);
   ```
2. Get the values from other arrays with that index, like this

   ```
   console.log(array2[index], array3[index]);
   ```

**Note:** If the value being searched is not found in the array, `indexOf` will not fail with an error but it will simply return `-1`. So, you might want to check before using that to access the elements from other arrays, like this

```
var index = array1.indexOf(4);
if (index !== -1) {
    console.log(array2[index], array3[index]);
} else {
    console.log("Invalid element selected");
}
```

Comment: (2a. test that the number was actually found, i.e. `index != -1`) - although the array access would yield `undefined` here which might be desirable

Comment: @Bergi Actually, OP says the user is picking the values from a dropdown box. That is why I left that.

Comment: Oh, right, but in that case you might not need to use `indexOf` at all and just apply `select2.options[select1.selectedIndex].value`…

Comment: @Bergi I am not very good with DOM. Could you please make that as an answer? That is very straight forward and simple. I would be happy to upvote :-)

Answer (score 3):

Any time you have multiple parallel arrays, you should really consider refactoring it into a single array of objects. That way you never have to worry about keeping them synched. For example:

```
var myArray = [ { val1: 2, val2: 30, val3: 36 }, { val1: 4, val2: 32, val3: 38 }, ...];
```

Now to find the value for `4` you can simply do something like (although a simple `for` loop might be more efficient since you know there is only ever one result):

```
var myValues = myArray.filter(function(item) { return item.val1 === 4 });
```

And then access `myValues[0].val2` and `myValues[0].val3`.

Or, if you are always looking up by the first value, you can use that as your key for an object that maps to your other two values. Something like:

```
var myArray = { 2: { val2: 30, val3: 36 }, 4: { val2: 32, val3: 38 },...};
```

Now if you want the other two values for `4` you can simply:

```
var value2 = myArray[4];
var value3 = myArray[4];
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming those are not only arrays and values, but you have actual `<select>` dropdown boxes:

Accessing the selected value is not only possible by using [`select1.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement), but also by using `select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].value`. That`.selectedIndex` is what we are interested in, and you can use that equivalently on the option collections of the other two dropdowns, or the arrays with their values:

```
select2.options[select1.selectedIndex].value
array2[select1.selectedIndex]
select3.options[select1.selectedIndex].value
array3[select1.selectedIndex]
```

If you access them via the `options` collection you will need to make sure that one option is actually selected (`select1.selectedIndex != -1`), otherwise you'd get an exception.

Comment: This is if and only if the array1 values and the select options have the same arrangement.  What if not? I wonder.

Comment: Yes, that's the premise (i took it for granted). Thanks for pointing it out! If they are somehow garbled, you'd need to search for it like in thefourtheye's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this,

```
var valueFromSelect = 4;


var array1 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22];
var array2 = [30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50];
var array3 = [36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54, 56];

for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
   if(valueFromSelect == array1[i]){
       console.log(array2[i], array3[i]);
       break;
   }
}
```

I suggest you don't use `indexOf`, it's not compatible with IE < 9 read more about that **[here indexOf MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)**

Comment: I wouldn't use a `for..in` to iterate other an array where a simple `for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)` would suffice.

Comment: I suggest [not to use `for…in` on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572). And if you want to support oldIE, then just *shim* `indexOf` instead of avoiding it!

Comment: @MattBurland yeah you are right, I was thinking of other language thanks for that.

Comment: @Bergi I think indexOf is not compatible with older IE

Comment: @andrex: It's compatible, it only isn't natively available. You can [trivially shim it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill)

Comment: @Bergi will I will just strongly suggest not to use it.  I will just go with what's on the table rather than forcing it.  They can also do that if they wanted to. :)

Comment: @andrex: What's "forcing it"? You are just providing a native implementation of `indexOf` if it's not already supported by the browser. The shim is actually pretty much what your code does anyway. It just searches through the array until it finds the matching element.

Comment: Sorry guys I guess I didn't understand the word `shim` sorry my bad.